# Getting actual image resolution from JFIF/EXIF (JPEG) header?

Tags: c++, c, header, jpeg, resolution

I've created a C++ structure for reading and verifying header of JFIF file-format.
The structure is as follows...

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct _JFIF_Header
{
    WORD SOIMarker;         // start of image marker
    WORD APP0_Marker;       // Application use marker
    WORD APP0_Length;       // Length of APP0 field
    BYTE Identifier[5];     // zero terminating string "JFIF",X'4A', X'46', X'49', X'46', X'00'
    BYTE Version[2];        // X'01',X'02'
    BYTE Units;             // units = 0:no units ;; units = 1:X and Y are dots per inch ;; units = 2:X and Y are dots per cm
    WORD XDensity;          // horizontal pixel density
    WORD YDensity;          // vertical pixel density
    BYTE XThumbnail;        // Thumbnail horizontal pixel density
    BYTE YThumbnail;        // Thumbnail vertical pixel density
}JFIFHeader;
```

Reading from raw disk clusters and copying these bytes in `JFIFHeader` Structure has done, and everything works fine.
Now, the problem is, values saved in `XDensity` and `YDensity` variables are very high (`X:24576,Y:24576` I read an image in Hex-Editor). This value cannot be the actual width and height of the image.
The value of `Units` is `0x01` , i.e. unit is in "pixels per inch".

How can I get the actual image resolution `1024x826` from these value ?
If this is not the right method, please give me any other alternative.

Comment: 24567 = 0x6000.  Swap the two bytes since you read them in the wrong order  = 0x0060 = 96.  96 dpi is a very common value.  Don't write your own jpeg decoder.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Just saw a example code. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can locate JPEG's `SOF0` marker (`0xC0`) and it is followed by 16-bit length, and then bits per pixel (8 bit), height (16 bit), width (16-bit) and component count (8 bit). All values are network byte order.

[image]

Image is `0x1C2` by `0x1C2` pixels (450x450).

Comment: Be careful This can grab the size of the thumbnail. Or even garbage from a block before the actual image `SOF0` block.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: How is it possible to grab something wrong? If you directly search for 0xFF 0xC0? If you skip the previous segments correctly (reading them one by one, skipping them according to their length) this should be totally fine, right?

Comment: Marker search: [Each marker consists of two bytes: an `FF` byte followed by a byte which is not equal to `00` or `FF` and...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format). There is also a link to spec there.